Misunderstanding of deriving gillespie's algorithm
I recently studied various stochastic methods. In this lecture note (Stochastic and Diffusive Processes lecture note by Dr. Luca Donati) and this book(Markov Processes: An Introduction for Physical Scientists, D. Gillespie, 1991), they are deriving Gillespie's algorithm using same way. But I cannot understand specific step of derivation of Gillespie's algorithm.
Here's my brief understanding of Gillespie's algorithm.

Introducing next-jump probability
$p(n',t+\tau+d\tau|n,t)$.

The next-jump probability can be written as
$$
p(n',t+\tau+d\tau|n,t) = q(n' \neq n, t+\tau+d\tau|n,t+\tau)\cdot(1-q(n' \neq n, t+\tau|n,t))\cdot w(n',t+\tau|n,t+\tau)
$$
. The first term is transition probability $n$ to $n'$ in time $(t+\tau,t+\tau+d\tau)$, second term is also transition probability but complementary event, the third term is transition probability $n$ to $n'$ at exact time $t+\tau$.

Calculate each  term.


I cannot understand how does next-jump probability could be written like step 2. I think the multiplication of first term and second term is next-jump probability itself, not multiply unnatural factor $w$. Do I misunderstand the concept of the transition probability?

The difference between $q$ and $p$ is not clear. Also, $w$ as stated is a Kronecker delta. The key idea to derive the Gillespie algorithm is to realize that the times between "jumps" or "transitions" in the system are random variables following an exponential distribution.
